# How to fix "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Island1.png": no such file or directory" error?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started coding with python and am having issues with getting the island sprite to show up, every time I run it said `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Island1.png": no such file or directory`.
This is what I've got:

```py
from tkinter import * #Import tkinter and os
import os

window = Tk() #Set up window
window.title("Game")
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.config(bg = "sky blue")

def game(): #Define game
    start_button.place_forget()
    quit_button.place_forget()
    scriptpath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    scriptdir = os.path.dirname(scriptpath)
    imagepath = os.path.join(scriptdir, "Island1.png")
    bg = PhotoImage(file=imagepath)
    start_island = Label(image = bg)
    start_island.place(x=100, y=100)


def quit_game(): #Define quit
    window.destroy()
    
start_button = Button(window, text="Play", command=game, height=3, width=35)
start_button.config(bg = "light blue") #Make buttons
start_button.place(x=700, y=600)
quit_button = Button(window, text="Quit", command=quit_game, height=3, width=35)
quit_button.config(bg = "light blue")
quit_button.place(x=700, y=675)

window.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Here is the image:
[Island1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d0c9.png)

Comment: is your image in the same folder as the python file? Also i think you should use `Label(image=bg)`

Comment: Yes, I put it in the same folder.

Comment: @Racerroar and from which folder did you run the python script ?

Comment: @Programmer A folder inside my projects folder inside the python default folder.

Comment: @Racerroar no, i mean, did you run the python script like this `python script.py` or like this `python path/to/script.py` or like this `python /pyth/to/script.py` ?

Comment: @Programmer I just pressed f5

Comment: @Racerroar does that mean you are developing in an IDE ?

Comment: @Programmer im using IDLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the full path to the image, so that it works independently of where the python script is run from. Don't worry : You do not have to type it in yourself, you can use `os.path` functions for that:

```py
# at the top of your script
import os

# your code ...


# in your game function
    scriptpath = os.path.abspath(__file__) # get the complete absolute path to this script
    scriptdir = os.path.dirname(scriptpath) # strip away the file name
    imagepath = os.path.join(scriptdir, "Island1.png") # join together the scriptdir and the name of the image
    bg = PhotoImage(file=imagepath) # make the image with the full path
```

Additionally, you have to use `Label(image=bg)` instead of `Label(bg=bg)` (the latter works only with a color name as string), and prevent `bg` from getting garbage collected, e.g. by declaring it globally. Here is the working script:

```py
from tkinter import * #Import tkinter and os
import os

window = Tk() #Set up window
window.title("Game")
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
window.config(bg = "sky blue")
scriptpath = os.path.abspath(__file__) # These
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(scriptpath) # three lines
imagepath = os.path.join(scriptdir, "Island1.gif") # can be shortened to
# imagepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "Island1.gif")
bg = PhotoImage(file=imagepath)

def game(): #Define game
    start_button.place_forget()
    quit_button.place_forget()
    start_island = Label(window, image=bg)
    start_island.place(x=100, y=100)

def quit_game(): #Define quit
    window.destroy()
    
start_button = Button(window, text="Play", command=game, height=3, width=35)
start_button.config(bg = "light blue") #Make buttons
start_button.place(x=700, y=600)

quit_button = Button(window, text="Quit", command=quit_game, height=3, width=35)
quit_button.config(bg = "light blue")
quit_button.place(x=700, y=675)

window.mainloop()
```

Note : `tkinter.PhotoImage` works only with GIF and PPM images, i converted the image for you, and you can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocadq.gif). You have to download this image and put it into the directory which contains the python script.

Comment: so this would work if I were to publish it cause it would be able to find it?

Comment: Yes @Racerroar , this will work for sure, as long as the image is in the same folder as the python script.

Comment: it works but I just get a white square not the image.

Comment: @Racerroar try to replace `Start_Island = Label(bg=bg)` with `Start_Island = Label(image=bg)`, and check if your Island1.png is something other than a white square !

Comment: what is what you have right now ? @Racerroar

Comment: I have it with 'Start_Island = Label(image=bg)'

Comment: @Racerroar ok, then try again the original version (`Start_Island = Label(bg=bg)`)

Comment: if I do that then I get a  'tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "pyimage1"' error, am i using colours it can't identify?

Comment: @Racerroar oof, i dont know, please try to view the image in an image viewer, and could you upload the image somewhere, so that i can test it ?

Comment: Ive put a link at the bottom of the question, i swiched back so i just get a white rectangle

Comment: @Racerroar ok i will test the code and the image ... But it can take a while ...

Comment: @Racerroar i worked it out now, the main problem (though not the only one) was that your `bg` was getting garbage collected (destroyed) as soon as the game function finished. You can find the working code in my answer.

Comment: @Racerroar and please do not forget to accept my answer !

Comment: sorry i was offline