# How should I solve the error _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "sample.png": no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, file-upload

I have my code inside the same folder as my image. And get `error _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "sample.png": no such file or directory`
(I use visual studio code IDE)

I tried using PLE but that didn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk 
    
HEIGHT =  700 
Width = 800    

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT , width = Width)
canvas.pack()

background_image  = tk.PhotoImage(file = "sample.png")
back_label = tk.Label(root,Image = background_image)
back_label.place(relwidth = 1 ,relheight = 1)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How did you run your python script?

Comment: If it says no such file, it means no such file. Make sure the path is valid. Also it should be `image=background_image`.

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as the program running it? Try `./sample.png`

Comment: check this post it's the same probleme solved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089148/how-to-fix-tkinter-tclerror-couldnt-open-island1-png-no-such-file-or-dire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couldn't open “sample.png”: no such file or directory means your file is not at the correct place you have 2 choices either you move it to where you launch it or you use an absolute path

Answer (score 1):

It might also make a difference where you are executing the python script from if you are doing via terminal. If, for instance you are running a script from /home/usrname and executing something like >> ./downloads/src/run.py your relative path will be /home/usrname/, not /home/usrname/downloads/src/. If you navigate to that folder and try to run the python script it may suddenly find that image.

So the solution would be to use a fully qualified path for the image, or maybe there are better ways to set a relative path. idk

Comment: This worked. I was running the py file from the main folder instead of navigating to the folder where both my py file and the assets where located and running from there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think that you should use the whole image path (I am not sure but I am using ubuntu and I should use the full path). Then i change the code a bit and this works for me

```
import tkinter as tk 


HEIGHT =  700 
Width = 800


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT , width = Width)
canvas.pack()



background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file = "sample.png")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Your code is working. Make sure you don't change or convert filename extension like jpg to png.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same using building a tkinter app on my ubuntu. My issue was just the wrong file name.

Make sure your file name and file path are correct and you should be good to go.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/logo.png")
logo_widget = tk.Label(frame1, image=img, bg=bg_color)
logo_widget.pack()
```

OR

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="assets/logo.png")
logo_widget = tk.Label(frame1, image=img, bg=bg_color)
logo_widget.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of path.
you can simply solve the problem by writing:

```
'import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)'
```

This will print the current working directory.
if your image and python file is present in same directory then change the current  directory to that directory by going to terminal and change the directory using 'cd' command in windows.

```
Error:-

File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3218, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.jpg
```

Solution :-

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk()
cwd=os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
root.geometry("500x500")
root.minsize(100,100)
root.maxsize(1200,700)
i1 = Image.open("1.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i1)
l1 = Label(image=photo)
l1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Current working directory is :-

```
PS C:\Users\91840\Documents\Code Practice>
```

But python file and image is present in the

```
C:\Users\91840\Documents\Code Practice>Python Practice
```

After that I wrote :-

```
PS C:\Users\91840\Documents\Code Practice> cd Python Practice
```

and now the run the program and it is running perfectly.

```
Note:-
This is my answer on Stack overflow and 
 I will continue to contribute in solving problems of others.
```